# Allow/Whitelist specific words/codes to write in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow/whitelist only specific words/codes in textarea.

I've thought using regexp so it is easier to allow codes or some kind of product keys in textarea.

Example I want allow only 2 specific codes in textarea (ALLOW ONLY SPECIFIC WORDS OR CODES):

> 0FAR12345H00123C00001P
>
> 0FAR54321H00321C00001P

So I can't write into textarea (DISALLOWING WRITING RANDOMLY AND RANDOM CODES):

> hey
>
> 34FAR43..

You can only start in textarea with (Product code can start with only...):

> 0FAR54321H00321C
>
> 0FAR12345H00123C

Regexp example:

```
/^(0FAR12345H00123C|0FAR54321H00321C|)[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$/
```

I didn't find any help in google for allowing specific words or codes in textarea and block other random texts or codes what are not in the whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a check that could be done `onchange` which will fire after changes are made to the textarea.

```js
const CODE = ['0FAR12345H00123C', '0FAR54321H00321C'];
const reg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})$/;
const reg2 = /^(0FAR12345H00123C|0FAR54321H00321C)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$/;

// Ensure values been inserted are in correct format
function onInput() {
  let values = event.target.value
    .split('\n')
    .map(v => {
      v = v.trim().toUpperCase();
      if (v.length <= 16) {
        if (CODE[0].substr(0, v.length) != v &&
          CODE[1].substr(0, v.length) != v) {
          v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1);
        }
      } else if (!v.substr(16, 22).match(reg)) {
        v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1);
      }
      return v;
    }).join('\n');

  event.target.value = values;
}

// Truncate any incomplete or incorrect values added to textarea onchange
function onChange() {
  let values = event.target.value
    .split('\n')
    .map(v => {
      v = v.trim().toUpperCase();
      if (!v.match(reg2)) {
        v = '';
      }
      return v;
    }).join('\n');
  event.target.value = values;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="onInput()" onchange="onChange()">
0FAR12345H00123C00001P
0FAR54321H00321C00001P
0FAR54321H00321C999999
</textarea>
<br/>
<button>Submit (Fake)</button>
<br/>
<em>Submit to display the onchange results</em>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Of course, users can now guess the code, since only code characters are allowed! Also, the allowed code can be copy>pasted from the js file in the inspector 

Comment: How i disable random writing and Allow only these two product codes?
In your code I can write everything and if more than 2 product codes then error code 'There were to many values in textarea!'..

Comment: You could use the `oninput` event to check the value of the `textarea` on every keystroke (as opposed to `onchange`)

Comment: That's a good point @Kokodoko, server-side validation should also be used.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I think I explained badly, I want only allow my listed product codes.. So you cant type or paste 123 or abc it must start like product code. Its like whitelist for textarea what you can only type. Image: [EXPLAIN](https://pasteboard.co/IfVEYkJ.png)

Comment: @KristenL I've updated to restrict users typing in values that do not match the pattern. After all changes are made to the `textarea` and the user clicks outside of it, it will check for complete matches, and truncate anything  that does not match.  Note: there are some flaws with this design (updating a character anywhere but the tail of the string may cause some confusion), but this will be a good starting point for you. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina One little question again.. But if I have different sizes product codes? 0FAR12345H00123C, 0FAR123H0012C, 01H01C.. You have static numbers 16 and 22..

Comment: The functions would have to be re worked, there's no way around that